# Verify if the element is readonly or disabled

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I have written a function where it checks if the field is read-only or disabled. However, first it check if that element field is present

This is my working function, but i feel like this is too messy:

```
def verifyReadOnly(self):
        if self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='cname']"):
            self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='cname' and @readonly='readonly']")
        elif self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='address']"):
            self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='address' and @readonly='readonly']")
        elif self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='address2']"):
            self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='address2' and @readonly='readonly']")
        elif self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='city']"):
            self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='city' and @readonly='readonly']")
        # country
        elif self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='country']"):
            self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='country']/../select[@disabled='disabled']")
        elif self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='state']"):
            self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='state' and @readonly='readonly']")
        elif self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='zip']"):
            self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='zip' and @readonly='readonly']")
        # EIN Custom field
        elif self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='cf_2698238']"):
            self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='cf_2698238' and @readonly='']")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several major issues in the code:

- violates the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself)
- *there is actually no element presence check* - `find_element_*` method will fail with `NoSuchElementException` if the element is not found (well, you may be handling the exception outside of the method, but that *scatters the logic too much* resulting into more ["spaghetti code"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code))

Instead, I would follow the [Page Object pattern](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/page-objects.html) and build a "Page Element" abstraction, where every element will have the `read_only` [property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330160/how-does-the-property-decorator-work):

```
class BasePageElement(object):
    # other methods here

    @property
    def read_only(self):
        elm = self.driver.find_element(*self.locator)
        return bool(elm.get_attribute("readonly"))


class AddressElement(BasePageElement):
    locator = (By.ID, "address")
```

Note that I'm using the `By.ID` locator here and the `.get_attribute()` method as opposed to less readable and more fragile XPath approach.

This, though, does not handle the "element is not present" case properly - you may wrap the `.find_element()` call with `try/except` or think of a more generic way to handle it.

Comment: however it could have this as well - self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='country']/../select[@disabled='disabled']")

Comment: not just read only

Comment: @user7242550 right, but you can hide this in the `locator` attribute of your element.

Comment: @user7242550 or, you may extend the `read_only` logic and add the "is disabled" check with [`is_enabled()` method](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.is_enabled).

Comment: I tried to read the doc. Can you please why we used @property here?